# Cannot sent reset password mails in rails application with a timeout situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, timeout, reset-password

I'm very new to Rails. Now I have a problem with sending reset password emails on Rails website.

Right now the problem is when I enter a registered email to reset the password, the email cannot be sent.

Net::OpenTimeout in PasswordResetsController#create

I think the problem is about the stmp setting.

Here is some of my code. By the way, I'm doing all these in the development environment.

development.rb

```
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 
                               "http://localhost:3000" }
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address          => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port             => "587",
      :domain           => "Here I put my intern company",
      # :domain           => "gmail.com",
      :authentication   => :plain,
      :user_name        => "Here I put my actual email",
      :password         => "The password of my actual email",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
```

password_resets_controller.rb

```
    def create
      # @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_resets]
      [:email].downcase)
      @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset]
      [:email].downcase)
      if @user
        @user.create_reset_digest
        @user.send_password_reset_email
        flash[:info] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Email address not found"
        render 'new'
      end
    end
```

user.rb

```
    def send_password_reset_email
        UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver_now
    end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
    class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
      default from: "naomi<noreply@MYINTERNCOMPANY.com>"

      def password_reset(user)
        @user = user
        mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Password reset')
      end

    end
```

application_mailer.rb

```
    class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
      default from: 'noreply@MYINTERNCOMPANY.com'
      layout 'mailer'
    end
```

Can anyone help with this?

And also, after this how can I set the production environment so that the website can be deployed on Heroku?

Comment: This is from the console:                                                                 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34506ms (ActiveRecord: 34.9ms)
Net::OpenTimeout (Net::OpenTimeout):
app/models/user.rb:34:in `send_password_reset_email'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:14:in `create'
  Rendering /Users/Naomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
...                                                                                                                   ...

Comment: Try with domain: set as "gmail.com", another port and if still not you might need to enable support for less secure apps on your gmail account.

Comment: I think you should use localhost as the address of the smtp server in development and then you could use `mailcatcher` to catch your emails